# Why was this question closed without any comment?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question

I have a question about my Law Stack Exchange post: [Does using ads and making the app contain a book of affiliate links make someone an intermediary?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/59030/does-using-ads-and-making-the-app-contain-a-book-of-affiliate-links-make-someone)

The question referred to above (kept unedited) was closed for clarity while none mentioned any comment to really ask what difficulty they were having for understanding before mentioned question.

There does not seem to be any lack of clarity the question asked clearly  that:

"As intermediaries are defined by law as companies which **transmit, receive or store data** on someone else's behalf do **apps which implement ads for profit or affiliate links** fall under this as they are logically doing the same big thing?"

Then it was added:
"However it is the ad network that transmits the data or the isp in case of affiliate links so are app developes going to.not be intermediaries and they are not even capable of having ip addresses logged as law requires them to do mainly by way."

Where is the problem how does Law SE suggest writing "Are app developers intermediaries?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your jurisdiction is confusing.  You say it's about international law, but then you cite a definition from Indian law.

Second, "apps with ads and affiliate links" is pretty vague: what data are they handling on whose behalf, and what are they doing with it?  With a vague description like that, you're not going to be able to get a clearer answer than "well, it depends."

Finally, taking the time to edit and proofread your post would go a long way.  You say "the question asked clearly that..." but the quotes you give are *far* from that clear in the actual question.  I'm still not *entirely* certain what you mean by "My point is wether the the app given or ad network forms intermediary and in case an app with links are intermediary for" or "In case so there is no main m way to retain data."  If you'd put the time and effort you put into adding the details you wrote for this meta question into clarifying the original question in the first place, you'd have been in a better spot.

Comment: What I meant was that there are many affiliate marketing sites who pay people when people drive their users to the affiliates site .So will this fall under the definition of intermediary?How could I write it better?And the international definition fully doesn't seem to vary much.

Comment: Are you asking about the apps to which traffic is being driven, the affiliate marketing platform, or the affiliate?  What data are they transmitting and how, in this hypothetical?  Assume that the people reading your question are not experts in how affiliate marketing works.

Comment: See intermediates includes search  engines and 'indexing' so by showing users a prommotional message "on behalf of" the affiliate the app with the affiliate link is acting as intermediary.Also they 'index' affiliate links and have internl search engines m..

Comment: When speaking on ads they going help the ad networks by acting as intermediary by allowing the network access though their app doing.

Comment: Ok understood I did not explain the main topics.